# C++ утечка памяти c DPAPI CryptUnprotectData

Tags: c++, утечка-памяти, memory-management

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию дешифрования из DPAPI. Позже я заметил, что после моей функции в памяти забивается 8.13 kB. Я выполнил снятие памяти на каждой строке и выявил, что эту память занимает функция `CryptUnprotectData`. Это косяк тех программистов, которые писали эту функцию или мне просто нужно очистить определенные переменные? Или же есть какой то другой вариант?

```
#include <vector>
#include <wincrypt.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")

using namespace std;

void DecryptDPAPI(vector<byte> input, vector<byte> entropy)
{
    vector<byte> result; // + 0.04 KB

    DATA_BLOB inputBlob;
    inputBlob.cbData = input.size();
    inputBlob.pbData = &input[0];

    PDATA_BLOB entropyBlob = NULL;
    if (entropy.size() > 0)
    {
        entropyBlob = &DATA_BLOB();
        entropyBlob->cbData = entropy.size();
        entropyBlob->pbData = &entropy[0];
    }

    DATA_BLOB resultBlob;
    resultBlob.cbData = 0;
    resultBlob.pbData = NULL;

    if (CryptUnprotectData(&inputBlob, NULL, entropyBlob, NULL, NULL, CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE, &resultBlob)) // + 8.13 KB
    {
        result = vector<byte>(resultBlob.pbData, resultBlob.pbData + resultBlob.cbData); // + 0.04 KB
    }
}
```

Comment: Или же надо [внимательно прочитать документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptunprotectdata), в которой описываются все дальнейшие действия после использования функции (см. секцию Remarks).

Comment: Почистил все блобы. Все равно остается 8.10 kB.

Comment: Там еще сказано про `SecureZeroMemory`, но я не знаю, какую область им нужно чистить.